# Source Control Alternatives

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, tfs

Here in my job my boss let me access my computer from home with [Logmein](https://secure.logmein.com/BR/), but the experience of working with some seconds of delay is unacceptable for me, since we could resolve it by making the server access public. But this decision is not up to me, so I'm trying to find a way over it. I thought using my computer as local repository, since it is syncronized with TFS(we use team foundation server).

Anyone had to deal with this kind of situation ?

Resume: I have a computer which is syncronized with TFS, but this TFS is not public and   the only way of comunicatting with it, is this computer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you migrate your solution to the cloud and you can work,

link  : http://www.visualstudio.com/fr-fr

This link permit you to create `team project` based on `cloud`, but you must have small project and have right manager, cost can be big.

In the second time , you can merge with `Integration Platform TFS` two projects

link : http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'll try this solutions and update the post state later with properly updates. Thanks.

Comment: I'am happy to help you Diego Garcia Vieira